# SQL Query: how to sort and display row_number()

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate the number of rows grouped by two columns (User_location & Map_id), but it's not giving me the value that I want to see. Its only allowing me to group by one column.

| Session_id | User_location | Map_id | loc_div |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XD001 | Delta 1 | A1 | loc010 |
| XD002 | Delta 1 | A1 | loc020 |
| XD003 | Delta 1 | A1 | loc040 |
| XD004 | Delta 1 | A2 | loc050 |
| XD005 | Delta 1 | A2 | loc060 |
| XD006 | Delta 2 | A1 | loc070 |
| XD007 | Delta 2 | A2 | loc080 |
| XD008 | Delta 2 | A2 | loc090 |
| XD009 | Delta 2 | A1 | loc030 |

Used Code:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY User_location
    ORDER BY Map_id ASC) AS Row_Num, 
    Session_id, User_location, Map_id, loc_div 
FROM table
```

This is what I am getting.

| Row_num | Session_id | User_location | Map_id | loc_div |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XD001 | Delta 1 | A1 | loc010 |
| 2 | XD002 | Delta 1 | A1 | loc020 |
| 3 | XD003 | Delta 1 | A1 | loc040 |
| 4 | XD004 | Delta 1 | A2 | loc050 |
| 5 | XD005 | Delta 1 | A2 | loc060 |
| 1 | XD006 | Delta 2 | A1 | loc070 |
| 2 | XD009 | Delta 2 | A1 | loc030 |
| 3 | XD007 | Delta 2 | A2 | loc080 |
| 4 | XD008 | Delta 2 | A2 | loc090 |

Trying to achieve separate row numbers grouped by user_location and map_id like below

| Row_num | Session_id | User_location | Map_id | loc_div |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XD001 | Delta 1 | A1 | loc010 |
| 2 | XD002 | Delta 1 | A1 | loc020 |
| 3 | XD003 | Delta 1 | A1 | loc040 |
| 1 | XD004 | Delta 1 | A2 | loc050 |
| 2 | XD005 | Delta 1 | A2 | loc060 |
| 1 | XD006 | Delta 2 | A1 | loc070 |
| 2 | XD009 | Delta 2 | A1 | loc030 |
| 1 | XD007 | Delta 2 | A2 | loc080 |
| 2 | XD008 | Delta 2 | A2 | loc090 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add either the `Session_id` or the `loc_div` to the row number partition.  Assuming the latter, you may try:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_location, loc_div
                          ORDER BY Map_id) AS Row_Num, 
       Session_id, User_location, Map_id, loc_div 
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY User_location, Map_id, loc_div;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim . This worked with adding the map_id to the row number partition.

`
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_location, Map_id ORDER BY Map_id) AS Row_Num, 
       Session_id, User_location, Map_id, loc_div 
FROM Table
`